# Chrome inserts random whitespace

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've a page whose styling gets messed up in Chrome (no problem for Safari and others). It seems that it inserts for a reason some strange whitespace in the HTML that ruins my layout at the top of the page and in other places.
If I choose to see the source of my PHP page, what I see is:

```
<body><div id="header-outer">
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="site-logo" class="span5">
            <img src='logo.png' />
        </div> ... etc ...
```

(I've modified the PHP to have no space whatsoever between BODY and DIV). But when I open the developer tools what I see is:

```
<body>
    "" <- why?
    <div id="header-outer> etc. etc..
```

If I manually delete the "", the layout just goes fine. What is happening here? I'm puzzled.

**EDIT**: you can see the page at http://bit.ly/ZkZxVG
**EDIT**: I've tried to disable all extensions, but with no effect on my issue.

Hint: I'm using bootstrap and JQuery. Could they mess with the code?

Comment: Wild guess maybe you have some CSS doing `selector:after { content: ""; }` ?

Comment: I don't get this issue in Chrome (Version 25.0.1364.152).

Comment: @sweetamylase: Not so wild, maybe. As I've just written, I'm using bootstrap and JQuery, maybe there's some selector in those frameworks doing this

Comment: @otinanai: Same version for me...

Comment: Disabling javascript doesn't get rid of it, so you can rule out jquery. Best guess is the PHP since CSS doesn't manipulate the HTML. You could try span an html comment across the body and div to see if you can catch that space for now as a quick fix. `<body><!--` and `--><div id="header-outer">`

Comment: @thgaskell Thanks but the problem was already addressed, it was the BOM UTF8 encoding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really weird, you might have some undesired char within your file, try removing `<body><div id="header-outer">` and rewrite it down.

Try encoding your file with utf8 No BOM too and see if it resolves the problem.

More infos about utf8 BOM [here](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1).

Comment: I've been already retyping this many times with no success... but the BOM did the trick! Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm adding some infos about the NO BOM encoding.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Thats not white space, they must be a physical charter in there. This might not be displayed on your screen, but just press delete and backspace until you have the next element in your markup.

white space in HTML is completely ignored by the browser, it does not render it. Looking in Firebug you have `"&#65279;"` rendered when editing the item.